# Add and update entries in text file

Tags: powershell

I am looking for help with a PowerShell script.  I have a file named tnsnames.ora in which I need to update/add the entries if not present.

For example, if tcpnew1 is present then it should update its corresponding items otherwise if tcpnew1 is not present then whole new entries should get added. These entries can be in the format shown below or they can be in single line. Hence code should take care accordingly.

```
tcpnew1 = (description =
              (source_route=yes)
              (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1610)(host=spcstn))
              (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1580)(host=spcstn)))
              (connect_data=(service=sales1))
          )

tcpnew2 = (description =
              (source_route=yes)
              (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1610)(host=spcstn))
              (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1580)(host=spcstn)))
              (connect_data=(service=sales1))
          )

tcpnew = (description = (source_route=yes)(address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1610)(host=spcstn)) (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1580)(host=spcstn)))              (connect_data=(service=sales1))
          )
```

I am trying the method but it is not helpful.  Please could you advise how to make it dynamic and more accurate code.

```
$str="tcpnew1 = (description =
                  (source_route=yes)
                  (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1610)(host=spcstn))
                  (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1580)(host=spcstn)))
                  (connect_data=(service=sales1))
              )"


#$s = "Mailbox:9WJKDFH-FS349-1DSDS-OIFODJFDO-7F21-FC1BF02EFE26 (O'Hicks, Jeffery(X.))"
#PowerShell

#[regex]$rx = "Mailbox\:(?<guid>\S+)\s\((?<lastname>\S+),\s(?<firstname>\S+)\((?<initial>\w{1})"
[regex]$rx="(?<first1>\w+\S+ =)\s(?<sec>\(\w+\S+ =\s+\(\w+=\w+\))"  
$rx.Match($str)

$rx.GetGroupNames()
#$m.Groups["third"]
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. Please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have file which contains entries which i have to compare with above mentioned tnsnames.ora file and if anything is different then add those entries to tnsnames.ora file.